# Cannot use "map" function within async module

Tags: node.js, node-async

I am using node.js "async" module and need to use the "map" method.
Basically I have an array that contains other arrays. The inner arrays contains 2 elements, a type and an image filename.

```
var arr0 = [];
var arr1 = ["type1", "image1.jpg"];
jsonArr.push(obj1);
var arr2 = ["type2", "image2.jpg"];
jsonArr.push(obj2);
```

For each inner array, I want to get the base64 encoding of the image identified by the filename and add this encoding string as the third element of the array.

I'm doing something like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var async = require("async");

function getImageEncoding(arr, callback){
    console.log("getEncoding:" + arr + "\n");

    // Get image filename
    image = arr[1];

    // Read file and get base64 encoding
    fs.readFile(image, function(err, original_data){
    var base64Image = original_data.toString('base64');
    console.log("test:" + base64Image + "\n");

        // Modify current arr by appendingthe base64 encoding of the image
        callback(null, arr.push(base64Image));
    });
}

async.map(arr0, getImageEncoding, function(err, results){
console.log("in async.map: " + results + "\n");
});
```

I know the arr.push(base64Image) stuff is the thing that is not correct, but I cannot figure out how to return the modified element.

In map(arr, iterator, callback) documentation, it is specified:

"The iterator is called with an item from the array and a callback for when it has finished processing."

The thing is I cannot figure out how to feed the callback with the new arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `callback` in `getImageEncoding` is called with *the return value of `arr.push`* (which is `1`), not `arr` after `arr.push`, which is what you want.

```
function getImageEncoding(arr, callback){
    console.log("getEncoding:" + arr + "\n");

    // Get image filename
    image = arr[1];

    // Read file and get base64 encoding
    fs.readFile(image, function(err, original_data){
    var base64Image = original_data.toString('base64');
    console.log("test:" + base64Image + "\n");

        // Modify current arr by appendingthe base64 encoding of the image
        arr.push(base64Image);
        callback(err, arr);
    });
}

async.map(arr0, getImageEncoding, function(err, results){
console.log("in async.map: " + results + "\n");
});
```

Comment: But it's not true that parameters are passed by copy, they are indeed passed by reference. The code above _will_ modify the original array (i.e. `arr0[0] === results[0]` in the final callback).

Comment: @Linus I thought === was not a reference comparison operator but a comparison without conversion one. I did not found reference on v8 and node.js about this but in mozilla doc I found this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: @Linus Still according to mozilla doc, object value are reference so you were right: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 1):

You map it properly. You need to use the callback in the iterator, Try the documentation of [after](https://github.com/raynos/after.js#after.map)

```
var fs = require("fs");
var after = require("after");

function getImageEncoding(tuple, callback){
    fs.readFile(arr[1], function(err, data){
        if (err) return callback(err)
        callback(null, tuple.concat(data.toString('base64'))
    });
}

after.map(arr0, getImageEncoding, function(err, results){
    console.log("in after.map: " + results + "\n");
});
```

Comment: While after looks cool, the asker's problem seems to be that he wants the results to consist of the original arrays, but with base64 data as well.

Comment: Nice! Do you really have to pass an array to concat, though? Might be a browser thing I'm not familiar with, but it happily concats with plain parameters (yes, it's variadic too boot!).

Comment: @LinusGThiel your right, [it works](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.4) either way. Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you execute your callback with *the return value of `arr.push`* as your result, where you really want an array as the result. Just use `concat` instead:

```
callback(null, arr.concat(base64Image));
```