# How to correctly perform async I/O in map iterator in node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use “map” function within async module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518414/cannot-use-map-function-within-async-module)

I've got a problem like this:

```
    var paths = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3', ...]; //Some arbitrary array of paths

    var results; //I need to collect an array of results collected from these paths

results = paths.map(function(path){
  var tempResult;

  GetData(path, function(data){ //Third-party async I/O function which reads data from path
    tempResult = data;
  });

  return tempResult;
});

console.log(results); //returns something like [nothing, nothing, nothing, ...]
```

I can imagine why it happens (`return tempResult` fires before the async function returned any data - it's slow after all), but can't quite see how to make it right.

My guess is [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) might help, but I fail to see how right away.

Maybe someone more experienced in asynchronous programming might explain the way?

Comment: Actually, `async.map`'s only example covers a case that is almost identical to yours.

Comment: Hmm... Probably I don't get something... what should the signature for iterator be? Should it not return value (like result = GetData(...))?

Comment: Nevermind. Found a bit more helpful example [in this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518414/cannot-use-map-function-within-async-module) . Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
async.map(paths,function(path,callback){
    GetData(path,function(data){ callback(null,data); });
},function(error,results){
    if(error){ console.log('Error!'); return; }
    console.log(results);
    // do stuff with results
});
```

As you can see, you'll need to shift the code that processes the results into the function to be passed into `async.map`.

Comment: That's perfect! It explains how to get result from asynchronous iterator so much better than async docs. Thank you.